# What is the proper way of replacing a nested for loop with streams in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

While learning Java 8 streams and lambas, I tried to replace the following nested for loops with streams :

```
List<Long> deskIds = new ArrayList<>();
for(ProvidedService memberService : service.getAllNodesDepthFirst()){
   for(Desk d : memberService.getDesks()){
     deskIds.add(d.getId());
   }
}
```

The loop iterates a list of 'ProvidedService' objects, and for each one, iterates over a list property of 'Desk' objects, and extracts the 'Id' field to a list.

I came up with the following code using streams :

```
List<Long> deskIds = new ArrayList<>();
service.getAllNodesDepthFirst().stream().forEach(srv -> {
    deskIds.addAll(srv.getDesks().stream().map(Desk::getId).collect(Collectors.toList()));
});
```

Is it the proper/optimal way to do it ? Or is there a way to do this without the second nested stream ?

Comment: I think it is fine.There is no issue with your approach.

Comment: For more check this link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html

Comment: @Prakhar: yes my approach worked, but it was abit naive and I thought there should be some way to streamline it, like assylias demonstrated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I would probably write it like this:

```
List<Long> deskIds = service.getAllNodesDepthFirst().stream()
                                          .flatMap(p -> p.getDesks().stream())
                                          .map(Desk::getId)
                                          .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Yes, I was hoping there was something like 'flatMap' !

Comment: @assylias Is there any easy way if I want to get a map in the end instead of a List, where map being some id of ProvidedService and value being desk id.

Comment: @assylias I looked at groupingBy but it seems like I can get Map<String, List<String>> but I don't want that, I was hoping to get Map<String, String> . Can you suggest if ho I can get that?

Comment: It would make sense to ask a separate question for your specific see case.