# In Java 8: Making a Set<V> out of the objects in all lists that are values of a Map<K, List<V>>

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am learning to do thing using Java8 and Stream. I have a problem which I am trying to solve using java8 stream.

I have a Map with type `Map<String, List<Integer>> accountMap`
Data - `{0000132861=[6613, 6170, 6206], 0000135932=[6613, 6170, 6206], 0000122989=[6613, 6170, 6206], 0000138372=[3187, 6613, 8167, 6170, 6206], 0000138399=[6613, 6170, 6206]}`

I want all the unique integer values inside the Map.value().
Like `[3187, 6613, 8167, 6170, 6206]`

When I do `accountMap.values()` I get `List<List<Integer>>`
`[[6613, 6170, 6206], [6613, 6170, 6206], [6613, 6170, 6206], [3187, 6613, 8167, 6170, 6206], [6613, 6170, 6206]]`

When I do `accountUserMap.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toSet())` I get same data type `Set<List<Integer>> [[3187, 6613, 8167, 6170, 6206], [6613, 6170, 6206]]` But all the duplicate list are dropped.

I want to drop all the duplicate values and want to get `Set<Integer> [3187, 6613, 8167, 6170, 6206]`

There should be an efficient way to do it without using .forEach() or iterating the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to "flatten" the stream of values:

```
map.values().stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(toSet());
```

Alternatively, you can use the 3-argument `collect`:

```
map.values().stream()
    .collect(HashSet::new, Set::addAll, Set::addAll);
```

Answer (score 0):

Never used streams myself, but instead of just `stream()` in your code above, try:

```
stream().flatMap(p -> p.stream())
```

to unpack that next list level.

That's what this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27174700/what-is-the-proper-way-of-replacing-a-nested-for-loop-with-streams-in-java-8) suggests in a similar context