# Iterate nested object in java8

Tags: java, mongodb, collections, spring-data, java-stream

I'm new to java8.
I have the following classes.

```
class User {
  List<Vehicle> vehicle;
  private int vehiclecount;

  public List<Vehicle> getVehicle() {
        return vehicle;
  }
}

class Vehicle{
  String vehiclename;
  String vehiclecolor;
}
```

I am able to save this in mongo collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ca1e53a1a79607fcc9200f"), "_class" : "com.test.User", 
   "vechicle" : [ { "vehiclename" : "Car", "vehiclecolor" : "Blue" } ], 
   "count" : 1, "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-09-26T09:30:59.826Z") }
```

Now i pulled out the result based on spring mongo data repository. i want to iterate the above mongo collection so that i can only get the vehicle list 
I tried the below:

```
List<Vehicle> vehicle = result.stream().filter(vehicles->vehicles.getVehicle().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Please help im new to java8. Thanks in advance

Comment: `result` is a collection of users? and you want to obtain a collection of vehicles?

Comment: yes absolutely , result is a collection of users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way of replacing a nested for loop with streams in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27174700/what-is-the-proper-way-of-replacing-a-nested-for-loop-with-streams-in-java-8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly:

```
List<Vehicle> vehicles = 
    result.stream()
       .flatMap(user -> user.getVehicle().stream())
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: works like charm.. Thanks Eugune.. solved the problem.

Comment: sure ..definately. intially i accepted but it asked to wait for some time to accept an answer.

Comment: But when i try to iterate the list vehicles, im getting the entire vehicle object itself (result == com.test.Vehicle@17220255), i want to retrieve vehiclename and vehiclecolor of the vehicle.  Below is my code:                                   
               vehicles.forEach(result->System.out.println("result == "+result));

Comment: sorry missed to retrieve the properties from result object.vehicles.forEach(result->System.out.println("result == "+result.getvehiclename()+" color>>"+result.getvehiclecolor()));

Comment: is there a way to retrieve the "_id" field from the result stream?